# PayPal webhook equivalent in PayFlow Pro?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-ipn, payflowpro

1) How can I come to know if customer has been charged for recurring service in 
   PayFlow Pro?

2) Is there any webhook equivalent endpoint available in PayFlow Pro ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Chintan.  I thought Silent Transfer post was supposed to send all recurring payments back to my server.  Only payments taken from the Hosted Pages do that.  VERY unfortunate.  If you have found any solutions to your issue, I would be grateful to know.  I am starting to work on finding examples of the reporting API so I can try to "automate" posting of recurring payments in my database.

Comment: Hi Joe Thanks for your suggestion but there is a API which allow us to know the payment status for the recurring profile and we need to run custom window service to get the status of the every recurring profile.
Ref:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/recurring-billing/#managing-payflow-services

Inquiry (ACTION=I) in API call to get the status of recurring profile

Comment: Hi Chintan, The way I work around this is to run pull a report each day with the reporting api and check for any new payments and compare it to ones I've already seen.  I have to custom code receipts for the new payments.  The solution you provided would require me to run an inquiry on each profile individually.  With hundreds of profiles, that is just not workable.  I guess I was hoping there was a way to have a post back to my server when a recurring payment was created.   Thank you anyway for taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 0):

The Reporting API will be the configuration to use when searching for your recurring billing profiles. Here is a link from the Developer's Page showing how to perform this API call: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/reporting/#performing-api-searches

Alternatively, you can login to the Manager account and go through the reports manually and looking up the customer's profile information.

1. Login to the Payflow Gateway - https://manager.paypal.com
2. Click Service Settings
3. Under Recurring Billing click on Manage Profiles
4. Two options:
   a.  View all Active Profiles
   b.  Enter Profile ID
5. Select Search

Once you have located the profile opened you can click, "View Payments" and this will show you the history for the last payment successfully process.